# JSF Spring @Autowired Issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsf-2

I need suggestion on the below issue:

I have a JSF listener and I want to invoke a spring bean by auto-wiring. I'm getting null-pointer exception while trying to invoke userAuthService.getComponentSecurity() from the listener class. I'm using

- JSF 2.x
- Spring 3.2.4. release
- Tomcat 7.0.x

What am I missing? Please see below my code snippets:

**JSF Listener Code:**

```
@Component
public class FieldDisableListener implements SystemEventListener {

@Autowired
private UserAuthService userAuthService;

private void loadUserConfig() {
userAuthService.getComponentSecurity();
    ...
}
```

**Interface Class:**

```
public interface UserAuthService {
public ComponentSecurity getComponentSecurity();
}
```

**Implementation Class**

```
@Service
public class UserAuthServiceImpl implements UserAuthService{
public ComponentSecurity getComponentSecurity() {
}
```

**WEB-INF**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Add Support for Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.san.security.service,"/>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<application>
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
<variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
<system-event-listener>
    <system-event-listener-class>com.san.security.listeners.FieldDisableListener</system-event-listener-class>
    <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent</system-event-class>
</system-event-listener>
</application>
```

Comment: Your listener isn't spring managed, so spring will not do anything to it. You will actually have 2 instances at runtime, one managed by spring (which only takes up memory) and the actual one used managed by JSF.

Comment: so I think my question is how to resolve this..